# iOS In App Purchase: single user not receiving products

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase

I got a support request from single users (~ 0.001 %) that the app reports that the in app purchase product couldn't be received. They have been facing that problem for a few weeks now, so it's not just temporary. They told me that in app purchase isn't turned off on their device, they have the latest stable iOS installed.

What could be causing these issues for some users?

Comment: can you provide with the exact error message that they are getting, better if there is a screenshot too. 
Also provide with the steps that you have implemented in order to fetch products from itunes and displaying them.